# String / int Exception Catch in Java

Tags: java, exception

I created a demo sign up program with some added threads for testing. The username cannot be just numbers(example username = 141235) but it could be something like (username = John124). I have the generic exception invoked but it's not preventing it. Can anyone help?

```
package com.company;


import java.util.Scanner;


public class tested extends Thread {
    Scanner charles = new Scanner(System.in);
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("New User Sign On");
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println("Please Enter A New User Name");
        try{
        String choose = charles.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Submitting.....");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Cross Referencing Username......");
            //Checking for username in database
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("New Username Accepted");
            //Username added to database
            Thread.sleep(900);
            System.out.println("Your new username is "+choose+". Now enjoy our FREE services.");
    }catch (Exception e){
            getStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: _" I have the generic exception invoked but it's not preventing it"_ -- sorry, that is not parseable English.  Can you please clarify what you mean?  If there is an exception, please include the complete stack trace as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.  It replaces all numbers to blank.

```
do {
System.out.println("Please enter a username");
choose=charles.nextLine();
} while (choose.replaceAll("\\d", "").equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't debug your program because it does not appear to be complete.  However if part of your goal is to enforce certain rules on the username, then you should first define clearly what the rules are.  For example, would "123456a" be allowed? (It has both digits and alpha, but it also starts with a digit).  And then you can consider using **regular expression** to express your rules and do the checking for you.  The following program assumes a certain rules:

```
public class ValidUsername {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
                "123456"        // expect invalid: not start with alpha
                , "a123456"     // expect valid
                , "123456a"     // expect invalid: not start with alpha
                , ""            // expect invalid: not start with alpha
                , "a"           // expect valid
                , "a12345678"   // expect invalid: too many characters
        };

        /*
         * username must start with an alpha characters [a-zA-Z],
         * and then follow by not more than 7 alphanumeric characters
         */
        String regex = "[a-zA-Z]\\w{0,7}"; 
        for (String test: tests) {
            boolean match = test.matches(regex);
            System.out.format("test %10s %6s a valid username%n"
                    , test, (match ? "is" : "is not"));
        }
    }

}
```

Output of this program:

```
test     123456 is not a valid username
test    a123456     is a valid username
test    123456a is not a valid username
test            is not a valid username
test          a     is a valid username
test  a12345678 is not a valid username
```

Answer (score -1):

put the try statement inside of an if statement. The statement should have charles.hasNextLine() as it's condition.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?  You can provide sample code to illustrate your point.